# How to construct methods in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Class in my MVC app which I am calling in my contoller and getting values fill in my view

```
public class Mainclass
    {
    public List<main> mainset = new List<main>();
    public void Crudmain(string path) //Capital "C" => Create, "R" => Read, "U" => update
    {
        XDocument x = new XDocument(new XElement("mainset"));
        foreach (main main in mainset)
        {
            x.Root.Add(mainxml(main)); //mainxml creates xelements for main
        };
        x.Save(path + "/" + 0 + ".xml");
    }
     public class main
    {
        public personalinfo info { get; set; }
        public addressinfo currentaddr { get; set; }
        public addressinfo otheraddr { get; set; }
        public telephone currenttel { get; set; }
        public telephone othertel { get; set; }
     }
```

In my controller I call Crudmain() in the action.

```
        private main cb = new main(); 
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(string button, main x)
        // getting path via some long code
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        cb = x;
        cb.Crudmain(path);
        return View("Read", cb);
        }
        else
        {
         return View("Create", cb);
        }
```

I am getting the XML file but the data is empty. Even the Path which is dependent on the variable of a object in Personalinfo is correct but the data is empty. I have a feeling that the Crudmain is initializing a new main class. I have just transitioned from VB to C# and do not understand the methods very well can someone please help me figure out how to set the Mainclass to the one passed by controller in my code.

Comment: This would be a better question if you gave a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and a description of what it should have done.

Comment: For most intents and purposes there are much better ways to create xml documents in .net.  I agree with Kendall, give a description or example of the output and there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: Basically I just want a method so that the Crudmain(path) saves the XML with the datainside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private main cb = new main(); 

public ActionResult Create(string button, main x)

cb = x;
```

You're overwriting `cb` with `x`.  I assume `x` is actually blank.  But it's very hard to tell, because your code is not formatted or named well.  If `cb` is of type `main`, then it doesn't have a `Crudmain()` function - that function seems to only exist on the `Mainclass` class.

---

Another issue is that you're never putting any data into `mainset` in the `Mainclass` function.  You assign it a new list, but never do anything with it.  But that may just be because of the confused way your classes are formatted here.  `cb.Crudmain(path);` still appears to be entirely invalid.

Comment: X is blank when it is passed to the view but user fills it up. I have verified that once returned by the view it is not blank anymore.

Comment: @FloodGravemind - The code's not really clear enough for us to be able to help, but I edited another suggestion into my answer.

Comment: Apparently I didnt know how get set works in C and so my mainclass only had fields and no property. Thank you very much  for your help.